Cross-day realized volatility
I've been looking for papers on volatility forecast, and most of them focus either on daily volatility (often using daily returns to access predictions for monthly volatility). Others focus on intraday-volatility, where intra-day returns can be used.
However, I'm working on the forecast of volatility of returns between a given time in the a trading day and the same time on the consecutive trading day. What could I use in this case as an ex post variance to use as a benchmark for my models?
Simply using squared returns over say 15 minutes intervals seem wrong because there would be a large squared return due to the closing of the market and its reopening on the next day. It also would seem wrong to simply use the squared return over the whole period.
Is there any reference that has addressed this issue on the literature? Is there a consensus on how to benchmark a cross-day volatility forecast?

You mean comparing the volatility at eg. 12:00 PM between multiple consecutive days? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

@Pleb yes, I'm forecasting the volatility from 12h to 12h next trading day, and I need an ex-post comparison benchmark

Okay, your question is still quite vague. But, you can use intraday returns and calculate RV up until 12:00 to get your volatility estimate for that period. Then each vol-estimate is calculated on returns from 12:00 - 12:00 next day. Whether you use overnight returns is something you have to figure out yourself. Using overnight returns will give you more data, however, the data is illiquid and can cause discrepancies in the estimates.
